# FORM.payment_date is reserved name bug in Coldfusion causing PayPal IPN INVALID verification in CF9

Tags: paypal, coldfusion, paypal-ipn, coldfusion-9

**Run the following experiments on your ColdFusion server/development environment:**

**1)** Create the following, basic HTML form that submits to itself using the **post** method:

```
<form method="post">
    DATE: <input type="text" name="date" value="gfsgfdgfsd"><br>
    MARTIN: <input type="text" name="martin" value="beardy"><br>
    PAYMENT: <input type="text" name="payment" value="50 POUNDS"><br>
    PAYMENT_DATE: <input type="text" name="payment_date" value="06:05:13 Apr 09, 2014 PDT"><br>
    XEVI: <input type="text" name="xevi" value="cool"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>

<cfdump var="#FORM#" />
```

Now access the page and hit the `Submit` button. Notice you get the error `Form entries are incomplete or invalid`. Now remove the ' POUNDS' from the end of the `PAYMENT` field so the value only contains numeric values. Re-submit the form and notice the error goes away.

**2)** Now study the CF Dump of the FORM structure. Notice how `PAYMENT_DATE` is missing from the comma separated list under the `FIELDNAMES` element! Clearly it exists because it's visible as the penultimate element in the dump. So why is it not listed?

*Note: This strange bug wasted 4 hours of my life while trying to integrate the PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Notification) notification verification/validation stage which requires you to post everything back to the PayPal server with the arguments in the same order they were when submitted to you. Because `payment_date` was missing is was returning as **INVALID**. I fixed it with a dirty hack that looks for `mc_gross` while looping over fieldnames and inserts `payment_date` manually. Eerrgh, I feel unclean!*

**Experiment 1** proves that `FORM.PAYMENT` is a reserved value that must be numeric.

**Experiment 2** proves that `FORM.PAYMENT_DATE` is a reserved value that gets ignored when `FORM.FIELDNAMES` is populated.

**Why?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the form scope in ColdFusion anything ending in _date is reserved as per http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec173d0-7ffe.html for validation purposes.

I cannot replicate the issue you are having with 'payment' being an integer.  As soon as I change the payment_date field to paymentdate it submits just fine.

Comment: See [Validating form data using hidden fields](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7a7b.html) for details.

Comment: +1 to you as I was typing up a similar answer but you beat me to it. I was going to add this other documentation reference - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7a7b.html {edit} HA! and now I see that @Leigh also beat me to the comment. I must be slow today...

Comment: You can disable this feature in the Application.cfc file: this.serverSideFormValidation="false";

Comment: Oh and @RaymondCamden I'll see you at SOTR14 in a couple of 2 months! :-)

Comment: @RaymondCamden you so missed out on some *points* here. Your comment should have been an "answer".

Comment: Well, I think ntunney has a good answer - mine is just an additional point.

Comment: I have added `THIS.serverSideFormValidation = false` to my Application.cfc which stopped the behaviour in Experiment 1 but I am still not getting payment_date appearing in the `FIELDNAMES` element of FORM as in Experiment 2. :-S Are there any more settings related to this that I can turn off?